# How to trim a string in makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have this string `cccccc:dddddd`.

I want to get `cccccc` only.

I looked at makefile docs but still confused how to do this with make functions.

This doesn't work but I want to do something like match from `:` to end of line and trim all of that.

```
MY_VAR:=cccccc:dddddd
....
derp:
    echo $(subst :.*,"",$(MY_VAR))
```

`:dddddd` is not static so I can't just hardcode that in like `$(subst :dddddd,"",$(MY_VAR))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
MY_VAR := $(firstword $(subst :, ,$(MY_VAR))
```

Note this requires that "cccccc" does not contain whitespace.

Comment: very clever did not know firstword was a thing! yes that works

Comment: @red888 In [the manual: 8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)